# action filter globally giving Redirect Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter

I have a class called LockScreen, to block the application.
After blocking the screen, and reloading the page or entering one through the address I get an error because I always enter the LockScreen class and I got a loop.

How can I fix it? I need to redirect always to LockScreen view, but I don't wanna get a loop.

[image]

LockScreen Class:

```
namespace ApplicaAccWeb.Validators
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class LockScreenAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        public static int countLockScreen;
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                try
                {
                    var lockScreen = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["lockScreen"];

                    if ((string)lockScreen == "Lock")
                    {
                            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(
                            new { controller = "Account", action = "LockScreen" }));
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AccountController:

```
[Authorize]
[LockScreen]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
}
```

Action GET LockScreen:

```
public ActionResult LockScreen()
{
    ViewBag.Username = User.Identity.GetUserName();
    this.Session.Add("lockScreen", "Lock");
    return View();
}
```

Action POST LockScreen:

```
/// <summary>
/// Permite desbloquear la sesión de un usuario.
/// </summary>
[LogActionFilter]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> LockScreen(string UserName, string Password)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
    {
        // No cuenta los errores de inicio de sesión para el bloqueo de la cuenta
        // Para permitir que los errores de contraseña desencadenen el bloqueo de la cuenta, cambie a shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(UserName, Password, false, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                this.Session.Add("lockScreen", "UnLock");
                LockScreenAttribute.countLockScreen = 0;
                return Json(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "success", "Unlock satisfactorio." } });
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return Json(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "error", "Usuario bloqueado." } });
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            //return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Contraseña inválida.");
                return Json(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "error", "Contraseña inválida." } });

        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Username = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        return View();
    }
}
```

FilterConfig class:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    //    filters.Add(new LogActionFilter());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "globally"? Have you added the action filter to the global filters (in the `FilterConfig.cs` file)?

Comment: I add it to a post
This @ataravati

Answer (score 1):

You have not registered the `[LockScreen]` attribute as a global action filter, which is the right thing to do, but you have used it on your `AccountController`. That means the `[LockScreen]` action filter will be executed every time any of the actions of the Account controller is called, including the `LockScreen` action. So, when you redirect to the `LockScreen` action in the `[LockScreen]` action filter, the `[LockScreen]` action filter is called again, before the `LockScreen` action is called; and that causes the recursive loop. To avoid that, define your action filter at the action level and only for the actions that need it, not at the controller level. So, your Account controller should look like this:

```
[Authorize]
// Remove the [LockScreen] attribute
public class AccountController : Controller
{
}
```

Instead, add the `[LockScreen]` attribute to all the actions in the controller, except the `LockScreen` action.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: **SOLUTION**

Create a Class Called:

```
public class SkipImportantTaskAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Add Condition to my FilterAction "LockScreenAttribute":

```
namespace ApplicaAccWeb.Validators
{

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class LockScreenAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public static int countLockScreen;
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
   /// This is a new Code--------------------------------
            bool skipImportantTaskFilter = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(SkipImportantTaskAttribute), true) ||
                filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(SkipImportantTaskAttribute), true);

            if (!skipImportantTaskFilter)
            {
                PerformModelAlteration(filterContext);
            }

        }
     ////----------------------------------------------
    }
     ////Only entering here if Bool is true------------------------
    private void PerformModelAlteration(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var lockScreen = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["lockScreen"];

            if ((string)lockScreen == "Lock")
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(
                new { controller = "Account", action = "LockScreen" }));
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Next Add [SkipImportantTaskAttribute] to my Actions need Ignore

```
    [HttpPost]
    [SkipImportantTask]
    public async Task<ActionResult> LockScreen(string UserName, string Password)
    {
```

***IMPORTANT***
The Solution of @ataravati is Great.

Comment: This is not a good solution. It's too complicated for no good reason. You just use the action filter when you need it, and that's it.

Comment: I understand you @ataravati, but if i Use "BlockScreen" and i go back in navigator, is a problem!. The project is really big!